# Skip to High_voltage pages with simple_token_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

After setting up the gem into AppController i've tried to place some static pages in the land page using [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) but always shows the unauthorized error.

and i've tried to use their `before_action :authenticate_user!` to open up to High Voltage but still showing 401 Unauthorized.

is there any workaround on this?

> Started GET "/pages/about" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-29 15:29:51 -0300
>   Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"about"}
>   Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-29 15:29:51 -0300
>   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User,  fallback_to_devise: false
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:pages_controller]
def pages_controller
    HighVoltage::PagesController
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a public page you need skip the `authenticate_user!` filter. Use `skip_before_filter`

This might contain the answer you need -https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/issues/17

Comment: Rishav Rastogi thank you for your answer but skip_before_filter is deprecated in rails 5 and i tried it already. anyway. thank you